# Using pandas groupby but keeping the order of other columns, then shift within group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe `df` as shown below -

```
    a   b
0   1   23
1   2   67
2   1   98
3   1   45
4   2   64
5   3   76
```

I want to use `groupby` so the resulting dataframe is as follows -

```
    a   b
0   1   23
1   1   98
2   1   45
3   2   67
4   2   64
5   3   76
```

I tried `df.groupby(['a', 'b']).count().reset_index()` but it changes the order of rows in `'b'`
Next, how do I shift within a group? For example I want to groupby 'a' and shift 'b' by 1 position. So the grouped and shifted dataframe would like this -

```
    a   b
0   1   NA
1   1   23
2   1   98
3   2   NA
4   2   67
5   3   NA
```

Comment: It seems that you have two questions

Comment: Your `grouped` dataframe output looks like sorted dataframe. Is that what you want?

Comment: No. The grouped dataframe must contain col 'b' in the order in which it appeared in the original dataframe.

Comment: @Dani Mesejo, Yes there are 2 questions actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want the df to be sorted on `a`:

```
In [4501]: df = df.sort_values('a')

In [4502]: df
Out[4502]: 
   a   b
0  1  23
2  1  98
3  1  45
1  2  67
4  2  64
5  3  76
```

Now, you want to shift it by 1 per group:

```
In [4504]: df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].shift()

In [4505]: df
Out[4505]: 
   a     b
0  1   NaN
2  1  23.0
3  1  98.0
1  2   NaN
4  2  67.0
5  3   NaN
```

Comment: @PaulH Sure, I updated my answer as per your comment.